# Soil/moss pad after electrotherapy

Tags: physiotherapy

Recently I have injured my knee and currently I am doing an electrotherapy. After this my knee is always cooled and under a cool pad I get a pad/ bag filled with some kind of dark green soil/moss (?). I get a pad of this sometimes to take home, to put it on my knee.

What exactly is in the pad and can I use it to fertilize plants?

Comment: Hello Agnieszka. We cannot help you because you haven't told us anything about this pad other than that you got it after electrotherapy, for example the brand, the country or a picture of it. The question about plants is also not on topic for a site dedicated to medical science.